# FIrebase. User being registered as anonymous

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

i have a simple React signup application with firebase authentication. I'm using email and password to register users. Everything is working fine but the user is registered as (anonymous). I have enabled email/password authentication in firebase and I'm using createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import { auth } from "./../firebase";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import GoogleButton from "react-google-button";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";

export const Signup: React.FC = () => {
const emailRef = React.useRef<any>();
const passwordRef = React.useRef<any>();
const passwordConfirmRef = React.useRef<any>();
const [error, setError] = React.useState("");
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

const googleSignIn = () => {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  // signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
};

async function handleSubmit(e: any) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
    return setError("Passwords do not match");
  }

  try {
    setError("");
    setLoading(true);
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      emailRef.current!.value,
      passwordRef.current!.value
    );
  } catch {
    setError("Failed to create an account");
  }
  setLoading(false);
}
const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    await googleSignIn();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <Card sx={{ width: "400px" }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography textAlign="center" variant="h4" m={2}>
          Sign Up
        </Typography>
        {error && (
          <Alert severity="error" sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            Passwords do not match
          </Alert>
        )}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid
            container
            direction="column"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="stretch"
            gap={2}
          >
            <Grid xs={12} sm={6} item>
              <TextField
                label="Email"
                type="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                required
                ref={emailRef}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={12} sm={6} item>
              <TextField
                label="New Password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="new-password"
                placeholder="New Password"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                required
                ref={passwordRef}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={12} sm={6} item>
              <TextField
                label="Confirm Password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="new-password"
                placeholder="Confirm New Password"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                required
                ref={passwordConfirmRef}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}
            fullWidth
            disabled={loading}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
    <Box component="div" marginTop={2} textAlign="center">
      <GoogleButton
        style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: 15 }}
        onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}
      />
      <Typography
        variant="body1"
        component="a"
        href="#"
        sx={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
      >
        <Link to="/login" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          Already have an account? Log in
        </Link>
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  </>
);
```

};

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you should be passing the auth as the first prop in createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password): [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account:~:text=createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth%2C%20email%2C%20password)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account:%7E:text=createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth%2C%20email%2C%20password))

Also, make sure your email and password contain values and are not undefined.

```
try {
    setError("");
    setLoading(true);
    const auth = getAuth();
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    emailRef.current!.value,
    passwordRef.current!.value
    );
  } catch {
    setError("Failed to create an account");
  }
```